# Can many defined routes bloat application based on Slim framwork?

Tags: php, performance, routes, slim

I've defined many routes (all in main `index.php`) in my application based on Slim framework. I have doubts, if my application won't become "heavy" or bloated because of it?

Comment: How many is "many"? If it's 100 or 1K, I doubt you'll notice anything. If it's 1M, then you may need to rethink your design.

Comment: @halfer: Assuming there are 100 routes, won't this be noticeable when the app is accessed by many visitors?

Comment: 100 routes is a very small number - most routing systems just convert them to classes and add them to an array, which all happens in memory. You'd be optimising your database layer before micro-optimisations of this kind.

Answer (score 0):

You can create class which check for example first part of url and then include only this routers which you need.

Comment: Do you mean, all routes are put into separated file(s), then index.php include it/them?

Comment: @maspai yes, but dont include all only for example if slug starts with 'article' yiu can include article routes